# Spring boot Mongo Data org.springframework.data.mapping.context.InvalidPersistentPropertyPath

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I want to get my data with the date.

**DONT READ THIS**

"is it possible to query data with LocalDateTime class? I really don't have anything more to add but StackOverflow is telling me my question is all code so I'm adding this. still, Stackoverflow is telling me my question is mostly code so I'm just repeating myself. my question is self-explanatory I really don't know what more should I add"

**DONT READ THIS**

POJO:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Document(collection = "matches")
public class Match {

    @Id
    private long id;
    private String matchName;
    private LocalDateTime date;

    public static final String SEQUENCE_NAME = "matches";

}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface MatchRepository extends MongoRepository<Match,Long> {

    Page<Match> findAllByDate_DayOfMonth(int date_dayOfYear, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Service:

```
@Override
public Page<Match> findTodayMatches(int count, int page) {
    int mPage = page != 0 ? page - 1: 0;
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(mPage, count, Sort.by("date").ascending());
    return matchRepository.findAllByDate_DayOfMonth(LocalDateTime.now().getDayOfMonth(),pageable);
}
```

error:

```
    WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
    WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils (file:/C:/Users/ME/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.3.1/spring-core-5.3.1.jar) to constructor java.time.LocalDateTime(java.time.LocalDate,java.time.LocalTime)
    WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils
    WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
    WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
    2020-12-04 17:48:29.284 ERROR 13300 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.context.InvalidPersistentPropertyPath: No property 'dayOfMonth' found on class java.time.LocalDateTime! Did you mean: ?] with root cause
    
org.springframework.data.mapping.context.InvalidPersistentPropertyPath: No property 'dayOfMonth' found on class java.time.LocalDateTime! Did you mean: ?
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentPropertyPathFactory.createPersistentPropertyPath(PersistentPropertyPathFactory.java:205) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentPropertyPathFactory.lambda$getPersistentPropertyPath$1(PersistentPropertyPathFactory.java:172) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentMap.java:330) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentPropertyPathFactory.getPersistentPropertyPath(PersistentPropertyPathFactory.java:171) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentPropertyPathFactory.from(PersistentPropertyPathFactory.java:86) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.PersistentPropertyPathFactory.from(PersistentPropertyPathFactory.java:99) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentPropertyPath(AbstractMappingContext.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryCreator.create(MongoQueryCreator.java:118) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.MongoQueryCreator.create(MongoQueryCreator.java:65) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:119) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:95) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.PartTreeMongoQuery.createQuery(PartTreeMongoQuery.java:89) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.doExecute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:122) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query.AbstractMongoQuery.execute(AbstractMongoQuery.java:107) ~[spring-data-mongodb-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.4.1.jar:2.4.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.findAllByDate_DayOfMonth(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.findAllByDate_DayOfMonth(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to query the collection by the *day of the month*. And, the repository query is as below:

```
@Query("{ $expr: { $eq: [ { $dayOfMonth: '$date' }, ?0 ] } }")
List<Match> findAllByDayOfMonth(int dayOfMonth);
```

The code `repo.findAllByDayOfMonth(4)` returns all documents from the database with `date` field values such as `ISODate("2020-12-04T08:50:00Z")` and `ISODate("2019-04-04T09:45:00Z")`.

Another way is to implement the repository method (in an repository implementation class). But, the above solution is simpler and clearer.

The exception you are getting is `org.springframework.data.mapping.context.InvalidPersistentPropertyPath` says "Exception to indicate a source path couldn't be resolved into a PersistentPropertyPath completely.".  `java.time.LocalDateTime` does have a `getDayOfMonth()` method. But, I don't know if you can use a JDK API class method in the way you are intending.

The code I had tried was with Spring Boot v2.4 and MongoDB v4.2.8.